# PHP + MySQL transaction+syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

First of all I'm new in web development so sorry if its a dumb question,I have an array, that the keys of the array are the id of the records that need to be updated in the database, i came with the bellow code to create the query and using mysql transaction to run the query (since few records should be updated together). the generated query works fine when i run it using command line, but with php code NO!

The code to generate the query :

```
$insert="";

if($run==true){

foreach($result as $key=>$x){


    $insert = $insert ."update project set type='".$x."' "."where "."id=".$key.";";


    }

//echo $insert;
$insert=$insert ."COMMIT;";
$insert= "START TRANSACTION;". $insert;
```

The result of the code:

```
START TRANSACTION;update project set type='project1' where id=1;update project set type='project2' where id=2;COMMIT;
```

The error that it gives me:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update project set type='project1' where id=1;update project set type='project2'' at line 1
```

I did not include the sql connections and... since i believe in high percentage they are fine, but in case its necessary i can include them too.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The older `mysql_*()` API and older drivers do\ not support multiple statements in a single query. Instead you must execute `mysql_query("START TRANSACTION"); mysql_query("INSERT...."); mysql_query("COMMIT");` as separate queries.

Comment: What function are you calling to execute the query?

Comment: *warning* your code maybe vulnerable to sql injection attack

Comment: @ Daniel A. White: thanks for reminding, yeah i believe it is, this is just a testing code for now, later on i will fix that problem.

Comment: @ G-Nugget: Ok about that i have a class that do the connections for,here is how i use it :$database_connection= new database_connection("....",".......",".......");
$database_connection->set_table_name("........");
$database_connection->set_query($insert);   /// $insert is the result of above code (the query)
$database_connection->connect();

Comment: @ G-Nugget:  it use =mysql_query($query1,$con1), to run it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to switch to PDO which has an interface to transactions directly.

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

$stmt = $db->prepare("update project set type= ? where id= ?");
$db->beginTransaction();

try {
  foreach ($result as $key => $x) {
    $db->execute(array($x, $key));
  }

  $db->commit();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  $db->rollBack();
  throw $e;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Multiple queries](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) are not supported using MySQL functions. You would need to break down the transaction:

```
$sql1 = UPDATE `project` SET `type`='project1' WHERE `id`=1;
$sql2 = UPDATE `project` SET `type`='project2' WHERE `id`=2;
```

You can however use [mysqli_mutli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) or as mentioned in another answer [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)